# Heroku Redis To Go

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

From command prompt I try adding Redis as `heroku addons:create redistogo:nano`

I get the following error

> Creating redistogo:nano on ***MyProjectName***... !!
>              Couldn't find that app.

I tried logging-in & installing from [Heroku/Redistogo](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/redistogo)
But Heroku ask for `CC` information even if I select free version of RedisToGo.

Is this normal on Heroku site?

Comment: why is this tagged with "android"?

Answer (score 2):

You should use this command:

`$ heroku addons:create redistogo:nano --app YourAPPName
... Creating redistogo:nano on ⬢ YourAPPName... free
... Created redistogo-URL-for-your-APP as REDISTOGO_URL
... Use heroku addons:docs redistogo to view documentation`

Comment: More generally, required and optional parameters for every heroku command can be found via `heroku <command> --help`, eg `heroku addons:create --help`